# Rails - How to access data generated in an initializer from controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, variables, singleton, initializer, rufus-scheduler

I have a ruby on rails app where I utilize AWS Products API.  This api has a throttle.  So I set up a scheduler using the rufus scheduler gem to to query the api every second, n times.  I put the scheduler in an initializer because I wanted to get the data as soon as possible.  But I'm struggling to successfully access the data from the controller.  I set up a singleton class with a class variable and getter and setter for it. And it works perfectly locally.  But when run it in my prod, the class variable is empty.  (I tried with an instance variable, but was getting nil in the setter)  I am at a lost and could use some help.

Here's my code:

aws_products.rb

```
require 'singleton'
require 'asin'

class AWSProducts
    include Singleton
    include ASIN::Client

    @@product_rewards = []

    def product_rewards
       @@product_rewards
    end
    def add_product_rewards(array)
       unless array.nil?
          @@product_rewards.concat array
       end
    end

    def get_aws_products (keywords, page)
      ...
    end
end
```

scheduler.rb

```
require 'rufus-scheduler'
require 'aws_products'

scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.singleton
@aws = AWSProducts.instance

product_count = 0

scheduler.every '1s', :blocking => true do |job|
    if product_count <= 5
        @aws.add_product_rewards( @aws.get_aws_products('Best Sellers', product_count) )
        product_count += 1
    else
        job.unschedule
    end
end
```

application_controller.rb

```
require 'aws_products'
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    def popular_products
        blacklist = Blacklist.all
        logger.info AWSProducts.instance.product_rewards.inspect
        @items = AWSProducts.instance.product_rewards.select{ |item| !blacklist.any?{ |o| item[:id].to_s == o.identifer } }
    end
end
```

EDIT:  I am hosting on AWS Elastic Beanstalk and deploy via the eb cli

Comment: What server are you running on? Webrick, Passenger, Unicorn, Thin, Puma?

Comment: @jmettraux Puma

Answer (score 3):

Try removing below line in class AWSProducts

```
@@product_rewards = []
```

And change product_rewards method in class AWSProducts as below:

```
def product_rewards
  @@product_rewards ||= []
end
```